# Как мне записать длинный текст в таблицу MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У меня есть код, при определенных действиях некая строка должна отправиться в базу данных MySQL.

*"Название товара: Candle box набор 200мл, количество: 7. Название товара: Вино и розовая малина 100мл, количество: 9. Название товара: Милый дом 100мл, количество: 5. Название товара: Кленовый чай и сладкий крем 100мл, количество: 1."*

**[image: Но текст обрезается меньше чем на половине.]** Как быть? И что делать? Возможно ли как то записать длинное значение в базу данных? Если нет, то что посоветуете?

Comment: Прочитай про нормализацию баз данных и его нормальные формы.

Comment: А записать ЭТО - тоже можно. Только в чём прикол такого вопроса и ответа?

Comment: Я хотел спросить, что сделать, чтобы большой текст не обрезался. Может где-то есть ограничение, при записи данных, либо еще что-то. Я только начал разбираться в MySQL, и уже есть проблемы.

Comment: Да, нужно правильный тип для колонки сделать..... нужен текст, сделай тип текст - https://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/column-types.html , https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/2.3.php

Comment: Та вот как раз таки менял, но не помогло. Уже и LONGTEXT применял, MEDIUMTEXT тоже. Ограничений в столбце нет(типо 11 символов и т.д)

Comment: А зачем тебе в колонке километровый текст? Опять же вернусь к своему первому комментарию: почитай про нормализацию....Судя по всему тебе это точно нужно

Comment: В любом случае не видя всю структуру твоей таблицы и полного текста (наверное  ты только часть привёл) и твоего кода (может быть в нём трабл) сложно сказать что-то ещё

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо огромное за помощь 

Comment: Либо режет клиент, вставляющий значение, либо клиент, показывающий полученное значение. Добавь в вывод LENGTH(column_name).